# problem when load a new scene in unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem, I'm making a 2d game in unity and i've create a scene that is load at the begining where my player is load, and then it sends it into the scene "salleA". I started by trying to lauch the game from this scene without adding a box collider for the walls of salleA, it worked. Then I added a box collider for the walls and it sends me to salleB, with a really strange display. Please I'm a beginner I don't understand. Here are the pictures :

salle A :
[image: salleA]

salle B :
[image: salleB]

and finally the strange display, when game is lauch but from the scene view :
[image: strange display]

I precise that the black squares are box collider trigger. The right one of salleA make you go to salle B and the left one of salleB make you go to salle A.

code of the first scene where the player is create :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class changeSalle : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Collider2D player;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("salleA");
        DontDestroyOnLoad(player);
    }

}
```

the collider of the player : (capsule)
[image: player collider]

the collider of the salleA : (edge)
[image: salleA collider]

After more searches, I think that the problem is more difficult. I tried to put a camera in the sceneA and lauch the scene, it sends me to salleB with the message "no camera rendering", that is normal because the camera is a child of player that isn't destroy on load of each scene. So I tried to remove the door to Salle B, I lauched and it sends me to salleC, the scene that you can reach by the left black square. Then I removed the door to salleC and I lauched. It lets me in the SalleA, but I only see yellow. Picture : [image: camera rendering]
I think nothing else is important, if you need something else tell me in the comments.
Thanks, Ilou.

Comment: Please add code and minimum way to reproduce this

Comment: at least show the code you are using , the box collider with gizmos or even the player box colliders

Comment: @BugFinder I had everything you need to reproduce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It now works, I tried so many things and I recreated the collider, I sized it to make it touch no other possible collider, like the sellers' collider, and it's good. I think that unity doesn't like when you overlap colliders.